# Truncating text from a database in Laravel 4

Tags: model, laravel, laravel-4, substring

I have a model that I am using to pull some data from my database with a query.  I am trying to shorten the text stored in one of the columns ("description").  Here is the model function:

```
public static function fan_likes() {
        $fan_likes = DB::table('fanartists')
                    ->join('artists', 'fanartists.artist_id', '=', 'artists.id')
                    ->where('fanartists.fan_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
                    ->select('artists.id', 'artists.stage_name', 'artists.city', 'artists.state', 'artists.image_path', 'artists.description')
                    ->get();


        return $fan_likes;

        }
```

Do you know how I can shorten "artists.description" to a limited character amount when pulling this data?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use Accessors and Mutators.](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) Inside your artists model:

```
public function getDescriptionAttribute($value)
{
      // Change 100 to be whatever length you want
      return substr($value, 0, 100);
}
```

Comment: and how would I implement this?  Call this in the view?  Or use this function in the model query.

Comment: @user1072337 whenever you want to get it vie $model->description it will be truncated.